# Как перейти с векторной карты с сохранением меток? OSMnx

Tags: python, openstreetmap, folium

Не могу допереть, как перейти с plot_graph на plot_graph_folium и сохранить при этом метки на карте, которые находятся в ax.

```
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, figsize=(10,10), show=False, close=False)
ax.scatter(longitude, latitude, c='red', s=5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем вам что-то доставать из ax.scatter, если у вас все есть в longitude и latitude?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox
import folium

place = "Anadyr, Russia"
G = ox.graph_from_place(place)#, network_type="drive")

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, figsize=(10,10), show=False, close=False)

longitude = 64.735814
latitude = 177.518913

ax.scatter(latitude, longitude, c='red', s=25)

graph_map = ox.plot_graph_folium(G, 
                                 popup_attribute='name', 
                                 edge_width=2)

def marker(long, lat):
    folium.CircleMarker(location=[lat, long], radius=2, weight=5, color="red").add_to(graph_map)

marker(latitude, longitude)

# сохранение и открытие:
import webbrowser
graph_map.save("mymap.html")
webbrowser.open("mymap.html")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но возник теперь другой вопрос, как я понимаю, через plt.show() такое не отобразить, необходимо сохранять результат в html файл или можно как-то сразу отобразить в отдельном окне?

Comment: результат придется сохранять. можно сразу же открывать полученный файл из самого скрипта. jupyter lab и jupyter notebook при выполнении этого кода сразу отображают его а IFrame. я дополнил ответ.